# How can I add fancy borders to the entire page in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, border

This seems to be a limitation to Writer, but I thought I'd ask anyway here, on the off chance someone has figured this out, and I'm missing something basic.

I'd like to add borders, such as stars or diamonds, to a Writer document but I only see very basic choices in the **Format** -> **Page** -> **Border** tab/pulldown. This would be the most logical place to do this operation but this dialog doesn't show any method for doing so.

[image: ss of writer dialog]

I've also looked on LibreOffice's forums and issue tracker and there are a number of tickets asking for this feature but nothing jumped out at me as either a solution or a workaround.

- [Bug 8275 - Summary: more border types (dashed, dotted, etc)](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=8275)
- [Bug 24923 - Summary: Borders as graphics](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=24923)

Additionally I've looked for LibreOffice Extensions that might suit my needs here but again nothing.

The only method I've found is to take a background image that contains the borders and to use that as a background for the entire page. This seems like a hack to me.

Has anyone figured out a method to do this beyond the use of a background image?

Comment: That second square under `Line arrangement` looks like it should give you a full-page border. It seems like those options go: None, Full, Sides, Top & Bottom, Left side only.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - thanks for replying. Yeah that part I understand. I want to change the symbols/characters used when I add a border.

Comment: Ahh, keyword "fancy borders". From what I can tell, you may be stuck with backgrounds. Best I can do is this post on the Libre Office Support Forum: http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/4909

Comment: @MichaelFrank - yeah I found that one too while googling. I can't believe this feature hasn't been implemented. There must be some technical reason, I'd be curious to know what it is, if any. Might be worth finding that and adding it to this Q so that others searching will find a reason why, and not a wall, such as the one we're running into 8-)

Comment: It's more than likely that if this feature hasn't been implemented it is due to a lack of art assets. Dotted, Dashed, and Full Line borders are fine as they aren't likely to require licensing, but a fancy/full art border has to be created by someone.

Comment: @MichaelFrank any news on the LibreOffice Fancy-Border option? Your link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that the answer to your question is the one you've come up with yourself.

That is to use an appropriate graphic in the background and anchored to the page.